# How to clearInterval on componentWillUnmount() correctly in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a table that renders a mapped `patientInfo array`. When the `patient.status` is not empty/has value, a countdown timer starts counting down for individual patient in the array. This happens on `componentDidMount()`. Now I want to clearInterval on `componentWillUnMount()` but the countdown timer doesn’t stop.

basically all I need is the countdown to clear when the time get to 0. Lets say the timer starts counting down from 60 secs when it gets to 0, clear interval. there is no stop button or anything like that to execute. I need it clear interval automatically when time gets to 0 sec. the countdown time start for individual patient when they have value in status. hope that makes sense

```
PatientInfo Array

patientInfo = [
           { count: 959999, room: "1", name: 'John Nero', status: ''},
           { count: 959999, room: "2", name: 'Shawn Michael', status: ''},
           { count: 959999, room: "3", name: 'Gereth Macneil', status: ''}
]
```

```
//starts countdown when the patient.status has value which comes from user input

componentDidMount() {

       this.countDownInterval = setInterval(() => {

           this.setState(prevState => ({

               patientInfo: prevState.patientInfo.map((patient) => {
                   if (patient.status !== '') {
                      // subtract a sec 
                       return { ...patient, count: patient.count - 1000};
                   }
                   return patient;
               })
           }));
       }, 1000);

   }
```

```
//when the patient.count is 950999 clearInterval doesn't work
//edited after some comments but still doesn't work

  componentWillUnmount() {

        this.state.patientInfo.map((patient) => {
            if (patient.count <= 950999) {
                clearInterval(this.countDownInterval);
            }
        });
    }
```

```
//after a few try the following seems to work but not sure if this is the correct way 


    componentDidMount() {


        this.countDownInterval = setInterval(() => {

            this.setState(prevState => ({

                patientInfo: prevState.patientInfo.map((patient) => {
                    if (patient.status !== '') {

                        if (patient.count <= 950999) {
                            clearInterval(this.countDownInterval);
                        }
                        return { ...patient, count: patient.count - 1000 };
                    }
                    return patient;
                })
            }));
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: [HINT] You can use simply `setInterval` instead of `window.setInterval`

Comment: why are you removing it inside of setState. WHy not just `componentWillUnmount() { clearInterval(this.countDownInterval); `

Comment: Your condition to `clearInterval` is too specific. In order for you to clear  interval, your component MUST be mounted for exactly 95 seconds and .999ms. I'm pretty sure JS can't even ensure that level of accuracy. Do you mean to do  `patient.count >== 950999`?

Comment: I think the idea of using `setState` inside of `componentWillUnmount` is not have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you are clearing the interval from a call to setState from `componentWillUnmount`. If the component is going to unmount there is not more state to set. The component won't be there.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount),

> componentWillUnmount() is invoked immediately before a component is unmounted and destroyed. Perform any necessary cleanup in this method, such as invalidating timers, canceling network requests, or cleaning up any subscriptions that were created in componentDidMount().

And

> You **should not call setState()** in componentWillUnmount() because the component will never be re-rendered. Once a component instance is unmounted, it will never be mounted again.

At max you can do this,

```
componentWillUnmount() {
   clearInterval(this.countDownInterval);
}
```

Comment: Hi I've tried what you suggested as well but that doesn't seem to do the work. I need the countdown to clear when the count for the patient gets to <=950999. @ravibagul91

Comment: You have weired use case here. Why do you need to do this? `componentWillUnmount` will get call just before your component get removed from DOM. Take your case, you want to `clearInterval` on condition `patient.count <= 950999`. But I think this is does not make any sense because every time component mounts, it will be re-initialized with initial state again.

Comment: basically all I need is the countdown to clear when the time get to 0 mins. Lets say the timer starts counting down from 60 secs when it gets to 0, clear interval. there is no stop button or anything like that to execute. I need it to do it automatically when time gets to 0 sec. the countdown time start for individual patient when they have value in status. @ravibagul91 hope that makes sense

Comment: You want to only clear interval or need to unmount the component also?

Comment: In this case you don't need `componentWillUnmount`, but try to do it in `componentDidMount` only.